# How to easily comply with these  API security requirments

Tags: html, api, forms, http-post

I'm working with a marketing company's web API and their authentication documentation says:

> Never put Web Endpoint details on the client-side portion of your
>   applications, where it can be easily read by anyone viewing the source
>   code.

Fair enough. My skills lay very much on the client side (HTML/CSS/JS), and when testing (by including the authentication info in the HTML) I've got no issues interacting with the API.

The authentication needs to be sent as a POST paramater with the other paramters.

Do I submit the form to a script on a server, which then adds the authentiction info and POSTs everything to the API? Or is there another way of doing this? Unfortunately there is no API key or anything simple like that.

As someone without any experience in that where do I start (apart from a question on stackoverflow) to find what I need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the client is a website or web application, you could implement it this way:

- POST the form to your own server.
- On the server, have some script that retrieves the data and then re-POST it to the API.

That way, the Web Endpoint doesn't appear in the client source code.

Comment: Thanks @Laurent, I was thought it would be like that. Where would I start looking to find what's needed to do that?

Comment: @acowley, for the first step, just use a basic HTML form and set the action to some URL on your server. For the second step, you can use Curl PHP to POST the data to the API end point.

Comment: Thanks again @Laurent, In the first step to I have to set a URL specifically for this task? What's involved with that? I use cURL heaps so hopefully should be able to work out the PHP implementation.

Comment: @acowley, yes you need to have a script (PHP for instance) on your server. You send data to it and it forwards it to the API. You cannot do what you want to do simply with HTML/JS.